# Wordpress: User group printing twice

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this following code that is printing twice the user group. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
$terms = array();
        $terms_tags = get_the_terms( $current_user->ID, array( 'user-group' )   ); 
        foreach ( $terms_tags as $term_tag ) {
          $terms[$term_tag->slug] = $term_tag->name;
          echo $term_tag->slug. ' ';
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [WordPress docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) are indicating that the second parameter for `get_the_terms()` should be a string, not an array. Could you check this?

Try it like this:

```
<?php
  $terms = array();
  $terms_tags = get_the_terms( $current_user->ID, 'user-group' ); 
  foreach ( $terms_tags as $term_tag ) {
    $terms[$term_tag->slug] = $term_tag->name;
    echo $term_tag->slug. ' ';
  }
?>
```

By now this is the only "problem" i see in your code.

Comment: No Still printing twice

Comment: @mysticalghoul ok I need more information. You are trying to retrieve what exactly? A taxonomy from a custom post type? Or really informations from a user?

Comment: Its custom post type that has categories that i have to compare with user groups with same name so what i am trying to print is a user group.

Comment: @mysticalghoul i tried the code on a local WordPress. It works perfectly fine. It must be another problem... Can you post the whole code of your template/function? And a screenshot whats exactly put out?

Comment: Its probably because i am trying to print in a plugin within a function.

Comment: @mysticalghoul can you post the whole code? Or a bit more so we can see what happens.... if this is in a function and you are echoing the the function it is possible that the output is printed twice